# Digital signature signing time

Tags: python, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature

Currently I am using `pyopenssl` for extraction of certificate info and validation of chain. But for expiration checking I need to extract signing time of the binary/certificate.

Is there a way to extract this info in Linux Environment ?

[image: Windows properties box]

Comment: What you're showing in the image is probably not the signing time of a certificate but of e.g. a CMS encoded binary. Could you check? Note that your use of tags and the fact that the image wasn't shown probably resulted in the low visibility of the question. Check the edits by clicking "edited ... ago". Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same need of getting the time a pe_file (Windows Binary) was signed.

It took me a while to figure out how to get this info using `signify` with python. They key was figuring out how to follow and use the graph in the `signify` docs here: https://signify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authenticode.html#pkcs7-objects

**See this example:**

```
from signify.authenticode.signed_pe import SignedPEFile

pathname = r"SoftwareUpdate.exe"

with open(pathname, "rb") as f:
    pefile = SignedPEFile(f)
    print(list(pefile.signed_datas)[0].signer_infos[0].countersigner.signing_time)
```

I tested this on Ubuntu against the [SoftwareUpdate.exe](https://github.com/ralphje/signify/blob/master/tests/test_data/SoftwareUpdate.exe) test file in the `signify` project:

```
tools/Python$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ralphje/signify/master/tests/test_data/SoftwareUpdate.exe
tools/Python$ python3 get_pefile_signify_time.py
2008-07-25 22:21:53+00:00
```

**Screenshot from Windows for the same:**

[image: screenshot of same info as above]

The snippet above is here: https://github.com/jgstew/tools/blob/master/Python/get_pefile_signify_time.py

This is the script I used to figure this out: https://github.com/jgstew/tools/blob/master/Python/get_pefile_signify.py

I have other pefile related examples in the folder.

**Related:**

- https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode
- https://github.com/sassoftware/relic
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269906/171387